# Determining whether an update inside a trigger function caused another trigger to fire

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I would like to know if an insert/update/delete action was called from inside another trigger function so that I can apply a trigger on table X that does not allow insert/update/delete actions unless the action is being performed from a trigger function on table Y.

Said differently, I would like to have a trigger on table Y when an insert/update/delete action is issued, check to see if the action was called from the table X trigger, and if so, proceed — otherwise, deny the action.

I also believe having the "source of request" information available to the trigger function could potentially help with debugging depending on one's hierarchy of triggers.

Answer (score 3):

What you are proposing here goes against the standard way of enabling or denying access to data in a database. Typically you would solve this by `GRANT`ing permissions on tables and functions. Your case could be solved like this:

First, create the tables with a specific role (= user, group), say "admin".

```
CREATE TABLE x (...);
ALTER TABLE x OWNER to admin; -- Not necessary if "admin" created the table

CREATE TABLE y (...);
ALTER TABLE y OWNER to admin;
```

At this point only role "admin" has access to the tables. If you want other users (say, role "app_user") to select from table `x` and select, insert, update and delete from table `y` then you should explicitly `GRANT` those permissions:

```
GRANT SELECT ON x TO app_user;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON y TO app_user;
```

You then define a trigger on table `y` and in the trigger function you cascade the changes to table `x`; I assume you have this sorted out. The trick here is to have the "admin" user as owner of the trigger function (which would be logical since only "admin" can `CREATE TRIGGER` on table `y`) and then use `SECURITY DEFINER`. This means that even if "app_user" does an `INSERT INTO y ...` which invokes the trigger, the trigger function that cascades an operation on table `x` is executed with the permissions of user "admin":

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_trigger_func RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  -- Perform some operation on x
  RETURN NEW; -- or OLD
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER;

ALTER FUNCTION my_trigger_func OWNER TO admin; -- If needed
REVOKE ALL ON FUNCTION my_trigger_func FROM public;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON y -- or AFTER, depending on your needs
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_func();
```

Note that you do not have to `GRANT EXECUTE` on the trigger function: because "app_user" has permissions on table `y` that invoke the trigger which runs the trigger function, "app_user" is permitted to execute the trigger function.

Following this procedure, the only way that "app_user" can modify table `x` is through table `y`. Use "admin" can directly modify table `x` but being the table and trigger owner this role should know better than to directly modify table `x`.